# How to add AndgularJS to existing fiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

In this fiddle I'm attempting to add AngularJS functionality :

http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/2020/

I've added angularjs to list of libraries.

How to add AngularJS library to fiddle ?

fiddle src :

```
<div ng-app>
    <span class="bold">Demonstrating filtering and sorting using Angular JS</span>
    <br /><br />
        <div ng-controller="ShoppingCartCtrl">        
            <div>Sort by: 
            <select ng-model="sortExpression">
                    <option value="Name">Name</option>
                    <option value="Price">Price</option>
                    <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div><strong>Filter Results</strong></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Any: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.$" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Price: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Price" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Quantity: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Quantity" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:mySortFunction | filter:search">
                        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
</div>
</div>

.bold { font-weight:bold; }

table td{
    padding: 10px;
}

table th{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

function ShoppingCartCtrl($scope)  {

        $scope.items = [
            {Name: "Soap", Price: "25", Quantity: "10"},
            {Name: "Shaving cream", Price: "50", Quantity: "15"},
            {Name: "Shampoo", Price: "100", Quantity: "5"}
        ];

        $scope.mySortFunction = funaction(item) {
            if(isNaN(item[$scope.sortExpression]))
                return item[$scope.sortExpression];
            return parseInt(item[$scope.sortExpression]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commited some mistakes:

1. You didn't instantiate your module;
2. You didn't instantiate your controller;
3. You typed the *keyword* `function` in a wrong way, you wrote `funaction`;

A *working* version:

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/M78zz/2022/)</kbd>